# How to secure parse server's _Installation, _Session and _Role classes?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I am building a mobile app and I use parse server as back end. I use cloud code for accessing parse database. Nobody needs to direct access to database. All data related operation done by cloud code api access. I deleted all custom classes' CLP permissions for all users and set correct permissions (Get and Create permissions granted, rest of them revoked) for _User class as documented. But I can't find any documentation about _Installation, _Session and _Role system created classes. How should I set CLP permissions for _Installation, _Session and _Role classes to secure the app and whole system. Thanks

Comment: I understand that those classes are secured by default. So you should be good by just keeping the default Parse Server settings.

Comment: for _Installation, _Session and _Role classes, all permissions (get, find, count, create, update, delete, add field) are granted for Public as default. Are you sure that this is secure.

Comment: I've just double checked here. _Installation and _Session are security edge cases, and are protected by default, regardless of CLP and ACL. For _Installation, it's documented here: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#security-edge-cases. For _Session, I didn't find on documentation but I tested. If you send a GET request to /classes/_Session, you either need to send the master key, or a session token (in this case you will retrieve only your own session). For _Role, I'd leave it public read, and write only with master key.

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I will leave them as default.